# Insertion of characters before and after selection in textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to insert a value before and after a selection within my textbox (upon click of a button).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

         $('.boldbutton').on('click', function(){

            var body = $("#id_body").val();
            var start = body.selectionStart;
            var end = body.selectionEnd;
            var selection = '<' + body.substring(start, end) + '>';

            text = body.substring(0, start) + selection + body.substring(end);
            $("#id_body").val(text);

         });  

    });

</script>
```

If I select 'a' and click the boldbutton, this is what appears in the textbox:

```
a<a>a
```

What should appear is

```
<a>
```

Any thoughts on why this is happening?

thanks!

Comment: `text =selection;` ? or `$("#id_body").val(selection);` ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean

Comment: why are you adding the selection again in the selection with added `<>` ?

Comment: Based on how the output of the code is, I think you're right, but I'm not sure what changes to make. Can you show me your suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: i suggest use the selection then add the `<>` which is already the selection variable

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$('.boldbutton').on('click', function(){

 var body = $("#id_body");
 var len = body.value.length;
 var start = body.selectionStart;
 var end = body.selectionEnd;
 var selection = body.value.substring(start, end);

 var replace = '<' + selection + '>';

 body.value =  body.value.substring(0,start) + replace + body.value.substring(end,len);

});
```

Comment: That works, but when there is additional content in the textarea, it gets included in the selection (i.e. selectionStart is always equal to the first char in the textbox and selectionEnd is always equal to the last char in the textbox). Do you know why this might be?

Comment: What is it you are trying to actually do with your code? Are you trying to add an anchor tag around the value of `$("#id_body")`?

Comment: I'm trying to add brackets around a string in the textbox (as chosen by the user) so that I can flag it and render it differently when rendering the page. Essentially, i'm trying to build a simple version of markdown.

Comment: Can you not just do this: `var selection = '<' + body + '>';`

Comment: I don't want to wrap the entire body in < >, just the text that the user selects in the textarea (i.e. #id_body)

Comment: Is `#id_body` not the ID for the text area?

Comment: While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.  Code-only answers are considered low-quality on SO.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that the text field has lost its focus by the time the button gets clicked, hence the empty text selection. One thing you could do is to keep a reference to the selected text **before** it actually loses the focus (with [`.blur()`](https://api.jquery.com/blur/)), and use this data on the button click handler instead of reading from the current state of the selection, which is again, empty.

```js
$('#id_body').blur(function(e) {
  $(this).data('selection', {
    start: this.selectionStart,
    end: this.selectionEnd
  });
})

$('.boldbutton').click(function() {
  var $body = $('#id_body');
  var sel = $body.data('selection');
  var text = $body.val();
  var start = sel.start;
  var end = sel.end;
  var selection = '<' + text.substring(start, end) + '>';

  if (end) {
    text = text.substring(0, start) + selection + text.substring(end);

    $body.val(text);

    $body[0].selectionStart = start;
    $body[0].selectionEnd = start + selection.length;
  }

  $body.focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="id_body" rows="4">Select some text</textarea>
<button class="boldbutton">Bold me</button>
```